# How to convert map data to list of objects in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dart

How can I convert map to list of objects in flutter.

Sample data,

```
 Model (
  key1: value1,
  key2: value2, 
  key3:value 3,
 )
```

Expected result,

```
  [0]: Model {key1:value1},
  [1]: Model {key2:value2},
  [2]: Model {key3:value3}
```

Comment: It's really unclear to me what you're asking for.  By "sample data", do you mean that you're invoking a constructor to some `Model` class with `key1`, `key2`, and `key3` named arguments?  Is it text that you need to parse?  Is `Model` supposed to be a `Map`? It's also unclear to me what the expect result is supposed to represent.

Comment: Sample data is a model class with key1, key2 and key3 are its fields. Corresponding value will be there for each fields. I have another model class with field1 and field2. Now I have to convert the sample data to the list of second model class. key1,key2 and key3 is in field1 and value1,value2 and value3 is in field2

Answer (score 1):

```
class SomeDataClass {
  final String option1;
  final String option2;
  final String option3;
  final String option4;
  final String option5;

  const SomeDataClass({
    @required this.option1,
    @required this.option2,
    @required this.option3,
    @required this.option4,
    @required this.option5,
  });

  factory SomeDataClass.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return SomeDataClass(
      option1: map['option1'] as String,
      option2: map['option2'] as String,
      option3: map['option3'] as String,
      option4: map['option4'] as String,
      option5: map['option5'] as String,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'option1': this.option1,
      'option2': this.option2,
      'option3': this.option3,
      'option4': this.option4,
      'option5': this.option5,
    };
  }
}

void main(){
  final optionsList = [
    {
      'option1': 'you can use fromMap and toMap methods',
      'option2': 'you can use some serialization libraries such as metinoned in opton 3',
      'option3': 'json_serializable',
      'option4': 'I am going to show you the from and to map method',
      'option5': 'good luck',
    }
    // there could be other options in the list.
  ];
  final someMappedObjectList = <SomeDataClass>[];
  for(var map in optionsList){
    final someObject = SomeDataClass.fromMap(map);
    someMappedObjectList.add(someObject);
  }
  
  // now you can use the someMappedObjectList.
}
```